# Jittery parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have wrote a website using parallax effect and having a few problems with jittery performance.

The page has been zoomed using CSS3 transform scale and on resize, automatically resizes the page using JavaScript / jQuery.

On the scroll, the backgrounds are positioned using scroll position on the wrapper box ( parallax backgrounds only inside ). With the image backgrounds moved on the scroll event using the CSS top position. The images have got a margin offset to give it the illusion of the position of the image staying still. I have enabled graphics acceleration and still getting jittery images on scrolling.

As I found out, CSS3 transform scale does not work with position fixed.

Any other solution?

Jittery parallax website: http://5starprmarketing.prosoftwareuk.co.uk/p/1750
Smooth parallax website: http://northeastexpo.co.uk/

Comment: Setting position via JS is generally more jittery, the "smooth" one you link is using fixed position images in the background, rather than animating them with the page.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use ready solutions like https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/?

Comment: The reason I didn't use a plugin was because of the zoom page requirement using the transform scale in css3 on the body tag.

Comment: May I ask why you're transforming the scale? It seems like a rather awkward way to manage sizes at a document level. (Plus, at certain aspect ratios it gets pretty unreadable)

Comment: Neither one of those sites uses parallax. The first one is (understandably) broken, and the second one just has a fixed background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried fixing the background using css:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

The example of the smooth parallax website uses this and is generally the best approach to keeping the background still while your content moves.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the page resources can also be optimized for better page performance. I noticed for me when your page was fully loaded the lag seemed to be less, so I believe there is an optimization issue.

Here is the analytics link I used that should help with some of that:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnortheastexpo.co.uk%2F&tab=desktop